# How to save a PHP content to file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, getid3

Hi I have just recently made a FLASH AS3 XML playlist player which works great apart from the part where I have to type all the XML out.
I have had some help with someone to compile this code that works great, but I want to be able to save the XML to file and not just read of it. And to update itself if the number of .mp3s in the given folder increases.

```
    require_once('getid3/getid3.php');
    $dir = $_GET['folder'];
    $xmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
    $xmlBody .= "<XML>";
    $getID3 = new getID3;
    $DirectoryToScan = 'SOUNDS';
    $dirHandle = opendir($dir);
    $strIsNull = "not found";
    $i = 0;
    while (($file = readdir($dirHandle)) !== false) {
       $FullFileName = realpath($dir.'/'.$file);
       if ((substr($FullFileName, 0, 1) != '.') && is_file($FullFileName)) {
         $i++;
         set_time_limit(30);
         $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($FullFileName);
         getid3_lib::CopyTagsToComments($ThisFileInfo);
         $xmlBody .= '<Song>';
         $xmlBody .= '<songNum>' . $i . '</songNum>
            <songURL>' .basename($ThisFileInfo['filenamepath']).'</songURL>
            <songArtist>' .(!empty($ThisFileInfo['comments_html']['artist']) ?  implode('<br>',$ThisFileInfo['comments_html']['artist'])  : $strIsNull) .'</songArtist>
            <songTitle>' .(!empty($ThisFileInfo['comments_html']['title']) ?implode('<br>', $ThisFileInfo['comments_html']['title'])  : $strIsNull) . '</songTitle>
            <songSize>'  .round($ThisFileInfo['audio']['bitrate'] / 1000).' kbps </songSize>
            <songDuration>' . $ThisFileInfo['playtime_string'].' </songDuration>';
          $xmlBody .= '</Song>';
       }
    }
    $xmlBody .= "</XML>";
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo $xmlBody;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `file_put_contents('playlist.m3u', $xmlBody);` to the end of the file - this will save the contents of the playlist in `playlist.m3u`. You can use this in tandem with all the code you already have, or just disable/remove the echo if you don't need it.

As for your second question - in order to have the file update with the new folder contents, you will need to:

a) Have another process monitor for changes, then call this php script/file
b) [Setup a cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) on your server
or
c) Call the script manually from time to time (or from your flash player), by calling for e.g. `http://localhost/my-m3u-generator.php`

Comment: Added the extra code and removed the echo as you suggested, but ran the code and didn't create .m3u file. Haven't tried your second suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps you do not have permissions to save a new file in that folder. One way around it is to create the file `playlist.m3u` manually, once, change it's permissions so that the script can access it (you can use 0777 to try,before dabbling further into the permissions) - and then re-running the script.